Flagging as off-topic still limited to meta
It's been 2.5 years since Flagging as off-topic limited to meta was asked, and there is still just one SE site to suggest as a better venue for an off-topic question.  The answers there suggested more options would be added.
The "flag as off-topic" option tree is frustrating to people trying to be helpful.  I followed the prompt tree, and – if I don't consider the question "blatantly off-topic" – I am forced to recommend it be sent to meta.crypto?  That's almost never what I think the best option is.
Are more options coming to this list?  Can we get the tree reworked if migrate is going to be so limited (so that we have more direction what the desired outcome is)?

Also see "Migration Paths for Crypto.SE"

On a side-note: I know the frustration that sometimes comes up from my non-mod times. In case of doubt, let me tell you that it’s already very helpfull when you “flag for moderator attention” with a comment that hints towards the site you think suits better. Those having access to the moderator interface can migrate questions to near to every site on the network, not only a limited list. (Back in my non-mod days I flagged so many Qs for migration that I even started to use a standard text for that, going Potential migration candidate towards SomeSiteThatFitsBetter.SE)

I'd guess the main candidates are security, SO, math and possibly software recommendations(in order). That is, besides META which may come in last. @e-sushi the off topic tree is frustrating me every time, from the start that I joined SO. My brain simply won't accept that I have to push "Other" instead of "Off topic" for "Off topic" questions. The SE maintainers have their heads very much in their *** on this issue if you ask me.

This looks a lot like a duplicate of the post @SEJPM linked to in the comment above.

Typically, once a site graduates, the top three or four successful migration sites (based on stats) plus meta are added.
You'll still need to use "other" to let mods know if you think a question should be migrated to some other site though.
